# Strategy for Updating Schema/Data of Data Stored in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

At my organization, we are using a stack of AWS S3, [AWS Glue](https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/glue/), and [Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) to drive some reporting of internal metrics. In general, this stack is great for quick set up for reporting off of raw data (stored in S3). The problem we've come against is what to do if we notice we need to somehow update the data that's already stored in S3. For example, we want to update values in a column that have a certain string to update that value.

Unlike a database, we can't just run a query to update all the existing data. I've tried to see if we can utilize [Glue Jobs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-jobs-job.html) to accomplish this, but from my limited understanding, it doesn't seem like it's meant to do ETL from a bucket back to the same bucket.

The only thing I can think is to write a custom tool that iterates through an S3 bucket, loads a file, provides the transformation, and puts it back, overwriting the original. It seems there has to be a better way though.

Comment: Updates directly are not possible because of s3 object's immutable nature. I have seen implementations of hudi on EMR which will allow you to do updates and inserts. You can refer to these here:
https://hudi.apache.org/docs/quick-start-guide.html#pyspark-example, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-insert-update-delete-data-on-s3-with-amazon-emr-and-apache-hudi/

Answer (score 2):

Updates are not handled in a native way in a traditional hive-like warehousing solution, which I deem Athena to be. A common solution is a kind of engineering workaround where you do "insert overwrite" a partition (borrowing Hive syntax, possible in Presto and hopefully also possible in Athena, which is based on Presto).

Other solutions include creating new tables and atomically replacing a view, which users are supposed to query, instead of querying the underlying table(s) directly.

As this is a common problem, there are also some ready to use solutions to it, but I do not know whether which/whether they are possible with Athena. They are certainly possible with Presto (Presto SQL):

- Hive ACID transactional tables (updates currently required Hive runtime)
- Data Lake (open sourced by Databricks; updates currently require Spark runtime)
- Hudi (I know little about this one)